# Vector spaces and linear transformations : showing that $f(ker(g\circ f)) = ker(g)\cap Im(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, soft-question, linear-transformations, first-order-logic

Source : Monier, *Mathématiques MPSI , Méthodes et exercices* , Dunod (ed).

---

My attempt :

> Exercice $19.1$ : Let $E,F,G$ be $K-$vector spaces. Let $f, g$ , be
> linear transformations respectively from $E$ to $F$, and from $F$ to
> $G$.
>
> To be proved : $f(ker(g\circ f)) = ker(g)\cap Im(f)$.

***(1) As to the $\rightarrow$ direction :***

Let $x\in f(ker(g\circ f))$ . By definition,  $x\in Im(f)$.

Also, $x\in f(ker(g\circ f))$ means that $x= f(a)$ with $a\in ker (g\circ f)$, that is,  with $g(f(a))= 0$.

Now suppose ( for refutation) , that $x\notin ker(g)$. It would imply that $g(x)\neq 0$, and therefore , that $g(f(a))\neq 0$, a contradiction.

We can conclude that : $f(ker(g\circ f)) \subseteq ker(g)\cap Im(f)$

***(2) As to the $\leftarrow$ inclusion :***

Suppose $x\in ker(g) \cap Im(f)$.

It first means that $x\in Im(f)$, i.e. that  $x\in F$ and that $x = f(a) $with $a\in E$.

Also, the hypothesis means that $x\in ker (g) \iff g(x)=0$.

Combining these two assertions, we have : $g(f(a)) = (g\circ f)(a) = 0$ , meaning that $a \in ker (g\circ f)$.

Since $x= f(a)$ and $a \in ker (g\circ f)$, $x\in f(ker (g\circ f))$.

We can conclude that : $ker(g)\cap Im(f) \subseteq f(ker (g\circ f))$.

Comment: There should be $g \circ f$

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake.

Comment: Your proof of $2)$ is fine. I do not see if it can be simplified. Concerning $1)$ Observe that $g(f(\ker(g\circ f))=(g\circ f)(\ker(g\circ f))=\{0\}.$ So $f(\ker(g\circ f))\subset \ker \,g.$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc  Thanks.